# How to make url point to both my server and website?

Tags: amazon-web-services, url, amazon-ec2, dns, cross-domain

I have a website url hosted with Google (and using Google DNS), and an AWS load balancer URL that points to my server, on an EC2 instance.

I want users to be able to access both my url by going to the address, but also process server requests at the same URL. My understanding is this is how it should be done, since I get CORS blocks when I try other domains or subdomains.

What i'm not getting is that I can only have 1 A record pointing to an IP address in DNS. How do I also point it at the server? Or is there some misunderstanding? Thank you.

My DNS looks like

```
A -> website
www A -> website
A -> server // Error. How do I do this?
```

Edit: I need a fetch request like this, where it fetches the local domain.
[image]

Comment: "I want users to be able to access both my url by going to the address, but also process server requests at the same URL." This is completely unclear. If you gave real names and real URLs, depicting real scenarios, it would be far simpler to help you, by first trying to fix a misunderstanding you may have in what the DNS does in relationship to what an HTTP server does (that one could do redirections or proxying based on the name or part of the URL)

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Of course. Just updated the post to show what I mean. I just want to fetch an express call from my local domain instead of needing to go to a separate domain. (I.E. fetch xyz123/create-payment-intent). So I need the EC2 instance where my server is hosted to point to this domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can do round robin DNS, in which case a single DNS name can point to multiple IP addresses.  But, in this case, it's acting as a poor man's load balancer, and regardless of which of the IP addreses is returned, they should all respond the same way.

In your case, it sounds like you want one DNS name to take you to two distinct servers, that serve different purposes, which doen't make sense to me.  When you resolve example.com, which IP address will it return?  How will you know?

You can do things like:

example.com -> A record points to IP address 1 (server)

example.com -> MX record points to IP address of mail server

[www.example.com](http://www.example.com) -> A record points to IP address 2 (website)

and etc....

In that case, exampl.com's A record points to a specific IP address, and the MX record points to a specfic mail server, and finally, you could have [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) (a different DNS name) point to the website.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I didn't know this was bad practice. So, should I just move my Google hosted website to my EC2 instance then?

Comment: That's one option.  Or, you could have multiple subdomains to point to different hosts...a.example.com points to EC2, b.example.com points to Google, etc....

Comment: Yes! That's what I was doing before, but I was getting CORS errors, since the domain isn't the same I suppose? Last question: How would I solve that problem? Thank you!

Comment: You can add an "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: \*.exmple.com" header.  The value of this header can be anything from '*' (allow all) to "thishost.ecmple.com" (allow one specific host only.)  If that's it, please remember to mark the answer as correct.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah that was it, thanks Mark.